# How to use variable as func in python?

Tags: python

```
def execute_as_vic(vic, cmd, a = None, b = None, c = None, d = None, e = None):
    if cmd in commands: #commands is a list
        if b == None and c == None and d == None and e == None and a != None:
            cmd(vic, a)
        if c == None and d == None and e == None and a != None and b != None:
            cmd(vic, a, b)
        if d == None and e == None and a != None and b != None and c != None:
            cmd(vic, a, b, c)
        if e == None and a != None and b != None and c != None and d != None:
            cmd(vic, a, b, c, d)
        if a != None and b != None and c != None and d != None and e != None:
            cmd(vic, a, b, c, d, e)
```

There's still problem of making it shorter, I think that "args*" i've seen before would work, but i have no idea how to use it :/ Can someone explain me that?

---

I'm keeping it in the same question because it's still the same script:

```
def execute_command(connection, victim, cmd, a = None, b = None, c = None, d = None, e = None):
```

where:
connection is user who executed execute command (hate that complicated shit)
 - victim is user who i want to execute that command
 - cmd is function to execute
 - a,b,c,d,e are args.

!VICTIM GETS TRANSFORMED INTO VIC! (and it's not the problem)

Error is: invalid number of arguments.

Comment: Have you tried the code you provided? it ought to work if `cmd` is a callable that accepts one paramter.

Comment: Where is the actual problem?

Comment: I've reduced your question text to just the essentials, but I don't understand what you mean by *as someone else*. Your `executecmd()` function works, you can pass in a function object and an argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think he means (at least this is what I understand from it) that he wants to run cmd as if it were another user account calling it? That's the only meaning I can assume from this. In anycase, flagging as unclear.

Comment: @JoeSmart: perhaps, but as that's pure speculation that really needs clarifying.

Comment: @JoeSmart, that's exactly what i meant :s Sorry for not being clear, just a bit tired today... :/

Comment: Running a function as a different user account needs more than just passing their name into it, unless your desired output is something as simple as `"Vic did this"` That code you put in your question is still not very helpful as we have no idea what `cmd` might be, it could be a very complicated function for all we know. Still need more information

Comment: @JoeSmart So again it's not clear ... Explaination:
vic is user's class, this one works for sure.
cmd is function. Imagine plenty functions. I want THIS execute function to execute some OTHER function as some user. That's messy.

Comment: Right, so vic is a class! That makes it a bit clearer. Might be worth specifying what `vic` is in this case. When passing it at as an argument it could be anything.

Comment: Nah, believe me, this one's not fail. This one works. This is just user. To be more specific, the script that runs that script has already got 'vic' as user, that's really not the case here.

Comment: I know, but we, as people trying to help you, didn't know that.

Comment: @JoeSmart, i know and I appreciate that you try to understand, but can you help me?

Comment: Look at the answer below. It explains how functions can take arguments that are other functions.

Comment: Updated the post. More specified problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass the function as an argument *without calling it*:

```
def fun(some_arg):
    print some_arg * 2

def executecmd(cmd, arg):
    cmd(arg)

executecmd(fun, 21)
```

Output:

```
42
```

There's really nothing more to it, functions are [first-class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) in Python.